# OpenCV - PCA analysis on BW image - area vs shape - is there already an implementation?

Tags: c++, opencv, shapes, pca, area

The shape of an object is detected on a bw image. The object is a black continuous shape, the background is white.
We use PCA (http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/dee/tutorial_introduction_to_pca.html) to get the object direction and align the object. Currently the shape itself (the points on the contour) is the input to the opencv PCA implementation. This usually works very well. But from time to time there is small dirt on the object border, causing the shape to pass around the dirt. This causes more points and more weight on one side, slightly turning the object.

Idea: Instead of the contour, we use the area of the object as input for our PCA analysis. The issue there, to check all points on if they are inside the contour and then use them for PCA slows the application down. This part will be about 52352 times slower.

New Approach: We take random points in the image, check if they are inside the shape and if so, use them for our PCA. We have to see if we can get the consistent quality needed from this approach.

Is there already a similar implementation in opencv which is using the area instead of the shape?
Another approach would be to put a mesh over the object and use the mesh points inside the object for PCA.
Is there already something similar available one can just use or does one quickly need to implement something like this?

Going for straight lines around the object isn't an option.

Comment: Any sample images you can share?

Comment: And also the relevant part of the code

Comment: Obtain the Fourier descriptors of the contour, set frequency components above a selected threshold to zero, then take the inverse Fourier transform. This way you can get a smoothed version of the contour, to which you can apply PCA. See [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FourierDescriptors/) for a nice demonstration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that we have received very limited information about your problem (posting images would help a lot) and you do not seem to know the probability density function of the noise, your best bet is to consider the noise to be Gaussian.

As such, and following your intuition, my suggested approach is to take a few (by a few I mean statistically relevant but not raising the computation time that much) random points that lie inside the object and compute the PCA.

Repeat this procedure in an iterative loop and store somewhere the resulting rotation angles you get from the application of the PCA to the object shape.

Stop once you have enough point, compute the mean of the rotation angles: this is a decent estimate of the true angle. Compute also the standard deviation to get a measure of the quality of your estimation. By "enough points" you can consider that ~30 points is usually considered to be "enough" for being representative of the underlying population according to the *central limit theorem*.

If you want, you can improve on this approach in many ways, for example doing robust estimation of the true angle once you have collected enough points. It all depends on the data you have at hand...take my suggestion just as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

There are few parameters that you could change, in which may improve your system.

First is the threshold you use to binarize your image. I don't know what your application is about, but you could use other color systems, or normalize your image by cromacity, and after that, apply the new threshold.

Other aspect is to exclude shapes (contours) that have bigger or smaller area that what you are expecting.

To add up, you may use a blur filter before detect contours.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the noise looks but when you say "small dirt" I think it might be only some few pixels that is a lot smaller then the object it self, but it might be attached to the object. To reduce this noise it might be possible to perform an opening (morphology) on the binary image.

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html